# Adding transition to a dropdown

Tags: html, css, transition, nav

I'm not sure if this can be done that way it was built but I'd like to add a transition effect to my dropdown. Anything that would make it seem less choppy. SLide, fade etc. Codepen below.

```
<div id="nav-wrap">

<ul>
    <li id="link-one" class="orange">
    <a href="#" class="parent-one-link"><span>Test</span></a>

     <div class="subnav">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.subnav -->

    </li>

    <li class="red"><a href="#"><span>Test</span></a></li>

    <li class="pink"><a href="#"><span>Test</span></a></li>

    <li class="purple"><a href="#"><span>Test</span></a></li>

    <li class="blue"><a href="#"><span>Test</span></a></li>

    <li class="green"><a href="#"><span>Test</span></a></li>

    <li class="yellow-facebook"><a href="#"><span></span></a></li>

</ul>

</div> <!-- nav-wrap -->

#nav-wrap .doubleLine {
  display: table-cell;
  line-height: 1.2em;
    width:65.275%;
}   

#nav-wrap {
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    font-weight:500;
    padding: 0;
    left:0;
    font-family: 'Raleway', Arial, sans-serif;
    z-index:100;
    float:left;
}

#nav-wrap ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#nav-wrap ul li {
    width:14.275%; /*  ~(100/7)  */
    display:block;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}   

#nav-wrap ul li + li {
  border-left: 1px #fff solid !important;
}

#nav-wrap ul li a {
    width:100%;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    color:#FFFFFF !important;
    text-decoration:none;
}

#nav-wrap ul li span {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100px;
    font-size:1.45em;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0 5% 0 5%; /* was 0 20px */ 
    line-height: 100px;
}

#nav-wrap ul li.yellow-facebook {
    width:14.275%;
}   

#nav-wrap ul li.yellow-facebook a {
    background-size:130px 26px; /* > 25px */
}

li .subnav {
  display: none;
  /*position: absolute;  */
  clear: both;
  margin-left: 0;
  font-size:0.9em;
}

.subnav ul {
  margin-left: 0;
  float:left;
  padding:0;
  width:100%;
}

.subnav ul li { 
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    width:100% !important;
    height:23px;
    float:none !important;
}

.subnav ul li a {
    padding: 10px 0 3px 0;
    /*background-image: url(../images/submenu-background-divider.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:left;*/
}

#nav-wrap .subnav ul li + li {
  border-left: none !important;
}   

.subnav {
    width:100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0.05% 0 0 0;
    border-top:#FFF 1px solid;
}

.subnav ul li a:link, a:active, a:visited {
  text-decoration:none;
}

.subnav ul li a:hover { 
  color:#000;
  text-decoration:none;
}

li:hover > .subnav {display:inline-block; left:0;}

#nav-wrap ul li.orange a {
    background-color:#f37028;
}
#nav-wrap ul li.orange a:hover {
    color: #231f20 !important;
}
#nav-wrap ul li.red a {
    background-color:#ed1b24;
}
#nav-wrap ul li.red a:hover {
    color: #231f20 !important;
}
#nav-wrap ul li.pink a {
    background-color:#e54198;
}
#nav-wrap ul li.pink a:hover {
    color: #231f20 !important;
}
#nav-wrap ul li.purple a {
    background-color:#6b439c;
}
#nav-wrap ul li.purple a:hover {
    color: #231f20 !important;
}
#nav-wrap ul li.blue a {
    background-color:#0193cf;
}
#nav-wrap ul li.blue a:hover {
    color: #231f20 !important;
}
#nav-wrap ul li.green a {
    background-color:#80c02c;
}
#nav-wrap ul li.green a:hover {
    color: #231f20 !important;
}
#nav-wrap ul li.yellow-facebook a {
    background-color:#fff300;
    background-image:url(../images/social-media/facebook-text.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
}
#nav-wrap ul li.yellow-facebook a:hover {
    color: #231f20;
    background-image:url(../images/social-media/facebook-text_over.png);
}
```

http://codepen.io/Compton/pen/jLGyo/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a CSS3 transition, only you would have to use opacity instead of display none.

add this

```
li:hover > .subnav {
  display:inline-block;
  left:0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in;
 -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in;
 -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in;
  opacity:1.0;
}
```

and change the display none to this:

```
li .subnav {
  opacity:0;
  /*position: absolute;  */
  clear: both;
  margin-left: 0;
  font-size:0.9em;
}
```

Jquery can do some sliding if you'd rather, but this is a little simpler to set up, you can also adjust the height to make it slide down if youd rather that instead of a fade in.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Bradley. That fade works well. How would I go about changing the height to make it slide out like you mentioned? I like the fade but I would also like to try this slide. I'm using one of them!

Comment: That would take a good bit more effort to do. but essentially, your just removing the heights from the elements and adding that easing to the hover state. you may have to rework the structure of your code a little bit to make it work. I'd recommend adding a set height to the subnav class and playing with it from there.

Comment: Great. I may come back and try that later. Thanks a lot for the help my man. Cheers!

Comment: How about setting `overflow: hidden` and transitioning `max-height` from `0` to (for example) `20em`?

Answer (score 0):

Put this to the animated element CSS:

```
transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-perspective: 1000;
```

It basically fools browser that the transition or animation is 3D and enables GPU acceleration and disables two-sided planes in webkit based browsers.